# compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{2^n}{n\cdot 5^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I consider the power series 
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{2^n}{n\cdot 5^n}}x^n$$
and find the radius is 
$$R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{5}{2}$$
so the power series is convergent on $(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2})$
then I use 
$$f'(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\Big(\frac{2}{5}\Big)^n}x^{n-1}$$
$$=\frac{2}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\Big(\frac{2x}{5}\Big)^k}$$
since when $x\in(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2})$, $\frac{2x}{5}<1$, then
by geometric series, 
$$=\frac{2}{5-2x}$$
$f(x)=\int f'(x) dx=-\ln |5-2x|$ and plug in $x=1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{2^n}{n\cdot 5^n}}=-\ln 3$$
But the sum of positive number can not be negative, it seems something wrong.
Could anyone point it out?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what you're asking, but I think the problem with the last step is that the indefinite integral doesn't exactly recover the function; there is the "$+C$" ambiguity that you forgot to take into account.

Comment: @EmorySun how is it unclear what is being asked?

Comment: @mathworker21 His title and the content of the post are inconsistent. Pardon me if I seem a little dense.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the integration constant. So you need to use $+C$. Once you have found $C$, you can find the series sum like you did before with $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the series center is indeed $x=0$ and you have the correct interval of convergence  (except up to the endpoints) $(-5/2,5/2)$. But this contradicts your radius, you want to check your computation for it. You should have $R=5/2$ from your interval.

The rest of the work is fine up until $f(x)= \int f'(x) \;dx$. Forget something? Remember that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2+2)= 2x$ but $\int 2x \;dx= x^2 +C$! So you have $f(x)= -\ln|5-2x| + C$. You need to plug in a value into the original series that you know the sum of (there is an easy value) then use this to find the integration constant. That should be the correction constant you are looking for. Another hint for $C$ can be [using the sum of the series here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2Fn*(2*1%2F5)%5En,%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D) Note you can also do [these checks from the start](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2Fn*(2*x%2F5)%5En,%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D).